# Conda environment changes which conda

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda, environment

I've been dealing with a bizarre phenomenon where `conda activate` occasionally says that conda is not set up to use conda activate as shown below:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I then get the `no action taken` output when running `conda init bash`

The ~/.bash_profile does include the conda init lines so that is not the issue.

I found that changing my conda environment switches which conda is being used. How do I fix this, as I think this is likely the root of the problem. (I'm assuming by setting the PATH somewhere)

How did this happen in the first place? Is there in initialization file somewhere for each conda environment?

Here is my ~/.bash_profile file if it helps to debug.

```
  1 export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
  2 export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
  3 export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
  4 
  5 export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:$PATH"
  6 export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/X.X.0/bin:$PATH"
  7 export PATH="/Users/anup/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"
  8 
  9 
 10 # >>> conda initialize >>>
 11 # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
 12 __conda_setup="$('/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/conda' 'she    ll.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
 13 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 14     eval "$__conda_setup"
 15 else
 16     if [ -f "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.    sh" ]; then
 17         . "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh    "
 18     else
 19         export PATH="/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:$PATH"
 20     fi
 21 fi
 22 unset __conda_setup
 23 # <<< conda initialize <<<
 24
```

Found that running with the full path `$ usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/conda activate vizfin` still returned the same `CommandNotFoundError`

[image: Activating conda environment changes which conda]

Comment: First off, `conda activate` is a *shell* function - it is not part of the `conda` entry point, but is instead defined when your shell sources the resource file (e.g., `.bash_profile`). That is why `/full/path/to/conda activate ...` doesn't work. Are you sure you are always in a **bash** shell? Newer macOS defaults to zsh. Another thing that could be happening is launching shell sessions without an `-l` flag (i.e., the resource file is not sourced). Also, why is there a `/usr/local/bin/conda`? Have you installed multiple times?

Comment: I have checked that I am within bash script by echoing $SHELL and also typing a nonsense command and seeing the output `bash: xyz command not found`

Comment: And this is just a straight bash session in Terminal? The fact that `which conda` changes isn't too much a concern: when **base** is activated then that `bin` should be prioritized. Otherwise, the code left by `conda init` usually adds `condabin/` to the PATH and that is where `which conda` will point whenever **base** is not active. That is by design and simply a linked version of the `bin/conda`. However, I am confused why you have a `conda` at `/usr/local/bin` - that is not a default installation location.